# Android RecyclerView Width wider than Screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, constraints, width

I am setting up a RecyclerView with CardViews. However, the CardViews are extending to the right side of the screen, despite all constraints. [image: CardView extending to the right side.]

Here is my code:

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Adapter:

```
class ExpertsRecyclerAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var expertsData: List<Map<String, Any>> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_experts_item, parent, false)
        return ExpertsViewHolder(v)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ExpertsViewHolder -> {
               // holder.setup(expertsData[position])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 10
    }

    fun submitList (data: List<Map<String, Any>> ) {
        expertsData = data
    }

    inner class ExpertsViewHolder constructor(expertsView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(expertsView) {
        fun setup(data: Map<String, Any>) {

        }
    }

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Fragment Containing RecyclerView

```
class ExpertsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var expertsAdapter: ExpertsRecyclerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_experts, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        initRecyclerView()
    }

    
    private fun initRecyclerView () {

        experts_recycler_view.hasFixedSize()
        experts_recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        experts_recycler_view.adapter = ExpertsRecyclerAdapter()
        experts_recycler_view.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        
    }

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
XML for RecyclerView Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/secondaryGray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/corner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
XML for RecyclerView Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/secondaryGray"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    tools:context=".ExpertsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/experts_recycler_view"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_alignParentRight="true", remove this from constraint layout

Comment: ^from XML for RecyclerView Fragment code

Comment: can you check my answer i update RecyclerView Item class you can check with that i not  sure but i think issue might be there other code looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple remove ConstraintLayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv_xxx"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure about this but you can try with below code also

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:padding="10dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:id="@+id/corner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I tried that. Still the same result. I think it's a runtime issue because it is displaying correctly in the XML preview. Might have to do with the fact that it's in a fragment. But anyways thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had mistakenly changed the width of the fragment above the bottom navigation bar.